# How to create Custom Textarea with auto suggest?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I want a **text area** which should have auto suggestions **inside** the text area. The suggestion list should be customized. Meaning, I should be able to send suggestion list from **back-end** or **from a source**.

For example: If i type **Be** , it should display a suggestion list near the typed word **Be** with Beast/Begin/Beans...etc(these are coming from my back-end, ajax call) .

Is there any **plugins** for javascript or Jquery or HTML/CSS etc ?

Comment: Try search terms like "autocomplete textarea stackoverflow" to see how others have done it. Note that questions about what libraries to use are off topic as mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) point 4.

Comment: There is no need to include any external plugin for this. whenever input changes, make your call...ajax/http/soap whatever it is.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure no this is not just a text box and then display suggestions. This will be a text area and have to list suggestions inside the textarea  near the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular 2. you can check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-mentions

Comment: using AngularJs.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mention
https://jsfiddle.net/biggieman/6j5v5856/5/